# Swagger not invoking WebAPI Custom ModelBinder

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, swagger

Goal: I am designing a REST API that allows user to pass parameters on the query string for an HTTP GET request. Something like

http://fake.api.com/search?param1=123&param2=car&pageSize=10

Implementation: on the server-side I have a custom model binder that get parameters from request querystring and converts them to a C# object so that my controller action method doesn't have to parse the query string. 
So the controller action method signature looks something like

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get([ModelBinder]RequestObject request)
```

When i test the api from Fiddler and pass the querystring values , the custom model binder works and i get the c# object with right values in controller action.

But when i test with the Swagger , the modelbinder is not invoked and the values are  null in the action parameter. And the model parameters are shown individually instead of showing the model.

How can i fix this?

My custom modelbinder:

```
   public class RequestObjectModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            if (bindingContext.ModelType != typeof(RequestObject))
            {
                return false;
            }

            var searchCriteria = new RequestObject();
            var type = searchCriteria.GetType();

            var querystringVals = actionContext.Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();
            var keyValuePairs = querystringVals as IList<KeyValuePair<string, string>> ?? querystringVals.ToList();
            if (!keyValuePairs.Any())
            {
                bindingContext.Model = searchCriteria;
                return true;
            }

            foreach (var value in keyValuePairs)
            {
                var key = value.Key;
                var prop = type.GetProperty(key, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
                if (prop == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                prop.SetValue(searchCriteria, Convert.ChangeType(value.Value,prop.PropertyType), null);
            }

            var validationResults = new Collection<ValidationResult>();
            var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(searchCriteria, new ValidationContext(searchCriteria, null, null), validationResults, true);
            if (!isValid)
            {
                foreach (var result in validationResults)
                {
                    bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError("", result.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }

            bindingContext.Model = searchCriteria;

            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get([FromUri]RequestObject request)
```

Should work given `RequestObject` has the following signature:

```
public class RequestObject
{
    public string param1 { get; set; }

    public string param2 { get; set; }

    public int pageSize { get; set; }
}
```

If you only have those three arguments and they are used infrequently, you could also do:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(
    [FromUri(Name="param1")] string parameterOne, 
    [FromUri(Name="param2")] string parameterTwo, 
    [FromUri(Name="pageSize")] int pageSize)
```

Notice how the query string names can differ from the methods parameter name.

**Update**

It seems like you are missing tagging the method or class with the custom model binder, e.g.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get([ModelBinder(typeof(RequestObjectModelBinder)]RequestObject request)
```

If you use the class one than once you can also tag the actual class, e.g.

```
[ModelBinder(typeof(RequestObjectModelBinder)
public class RequestObject {}
```

Comment: I have around 11 properties. I went for modelbinder because if i call the action without any querystring values, i would like to get the request with default property values. Without modelbinder it is not working.

Comment: If you post your custom model binder we could diagnose why this is happening. Have you created a custom model binder?

Comment: yes. i have updated my post with custom modelbinder. And when i use [FromUri] in the action method, the object is null. Could it be because i am using [Route("")]?

Comment: I have used custom ModelBinderProvider and configured in webapiconfig

Comment: If you look at the URL that swagger executes, does it include the prefix of the variable, e.g. `request.param1`?  I suspect it does if it is working manually but not via swagger. Usually this is solved by `[FromUri(Name="")]` but it in this instance won't work.

Comment: In swagger the parameter names are displaying with request.param1, request.param2... Is it possible to make as single model parameter instead of property by property?

Comment: You probably want to look at writing a swashbukcle operation filter, you'll be able to change the type listing. It's a shame that the model binder can't handle both naming schemes.

Answer (score -2):

Try this :-

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get([FromUri][ModelBinder]RequestObject request)
```

Comment: No. it is not working. Throwing following error: "Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Can't bind parameter 'searchCriteria' because it has conflicting attributes on it."